# Different approaches to accessing SSAS

Tags: mdx, ssas, adomd.net

I’m interested in knowing some different approaches for retrieving data from Analysis Services, to use in either objects in code, or for end-user reporting.

I’ve used two different approaches in the past, one was using ADOMD to pull results and put these into a dataset, the other was using SQL OPENQUERY to a linked SSAS server to get results out as a SQL stored procedure result set. Both of these had advantages and disadvantages.

Over the years I’ve seen various questions along this line, so forgive me for any duplication, but what other methods are there for getting SSAS data into a format where other people’s code could use it?

I’ve considered XML result sets from SSAS over HTTP, then Linq to XML – Anyone have any experience with that?

Ideally I’d like a dataset with typed columns, or objects with properties, but I’m more interested in general approach than code samples. How have you got data from SSAS, apart from SSRS/Other dashboard controls?

Answer (score 9):

I know MS is supposed to support XML/A (XML for Analysis). I am shortly releasing an ajax library to do XML/A requests from web pages.

While I am currently focused on Pentaho's Mondrian, it *should* work for MS SQLs XML/A too. If you are interested, I am doing a presentation on it on January 13. (see: http://wiki.pentaho.com/display/COM/January+13,+2010+-+Roland+Bouman+-+OLAP+and+Analysis+for+web+applications+using+XMLA) I will be releasing my code by that time too (probably underr a LGPL license)

I would love to get feedback from people that use other XML/A servers, so if you are interestd, it would be great to work together on this.

## UPDATE:

the project is now available at http://code.google.com/p/xmla4js/ There is API documentation, code samples, and build scripts. It's LGPL so you're free to use it in your applications, even for commercial purposes. The license does require that you release any modifications to the library itself as LGPL (but this does not affect the application that uses the library)

## UPDATE2

The project no resides on github at https://github.com/rpbouman/xmla4js
It works in the browser as well as in nodejs.

Comment: Hi Roland, an interesting approach and one I will take a look at. I'm more interested in access from (And usage by) middle-tier code at the moment. Many thanks for your suggestion.

Answer (score 4):

I've never used it myself, as we only use ADOMD and Excel to connect to SSAS, but at some point we considered using HTTP and XML. We ended up going the ADOMD route because of a shortened dev schedule, but I guess it's another option that allows for access to SSAS outside of the .Net world.

Here's a link which I found useful when prototyping: [Configuring HTTP Access to SQL Server 2008 Analysis Services on Microsoft Windows Server 2008](http://bloggingabout.net/blogs/mglaser/archive/2008/08/15/configuring-http-access-to-sql-server-2008-analysis-services-on-microsoft-windows-server-2008.aspx)

Answer (score 3):

XMLA is the "high power" approach -- but I'm not aware of a toolkit or library that really exposes the full capabilities of XMLA; I think you would have craft it up yourself. For the projects I've done, that's just way too much work.

Instead, I used ADOMD.NET for retrieving results in code; the CellSet class in particular is fairly rich.  For end user analysis (slice and dice), most often I use Excel Pivot Charts (which are fabulous!); sometimes I also use Visio Pivot Diagrams. For fixed reporting, Reporting Services can access SSAS directly, and it even has it's own query builder.

BTW, in case it helps, I have a chapter in my book about integrating SSAS with web sites as a way of offloading SQL Server: [Ultra-Fast ASP.NET](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1430223839). My code examples use ADOMD; I also walk through building a simple cube, configuring automatic updates with SSIS, using proactive caching, building simple MDX queries, etc.

Answer (score 2):

Another approach is to use the MSOLAP OLE DB provider.  Our code is currently using this method.

Comment: Does it work better than ADOMD? I ask because there are some annoyances with using ADOMD and so was curious if it's worth considering a move to that provider instead.

Comment: I thought it was much simpler to work with.  Result sets are flattened into two-dimensional tables you access through an IDataReader.  It has its quirks, however.  For example, I had to poke around in the debugger to figure out how it generates the result set column names for the dimensions.  Also, it's very loose with its types, so you must beware.  For example, if a value that could be floating-point happens to come out to a whole number, sometimes the type you get back is an int.  Had to create a suite of methods to properly extract the data.

Comment: Good to know, thanks. It seems that either way there is some work to be done :-S

Answer (score 2):

Another way (and I would say the simplest one) to get data from SSAS OLAP cubes into .NET is by using LINQ + ADO.NET Entity Framework + [SSAS Entity Framework Provider](http://www.agiledesignllc.com/Products.htm) .

(I work for the company that developed SSAS Entity Framework Provider).

Comment: Well done Sir, I actually took a run at this, went the same road of TTGen to create the annotated classes, but couldn't quite get the hang of creating an IQueryable provider...Well done you <3